# Get parameter from previous route handler in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Say I have *file1.js*:

```
import Router from "express-promise-router";

export const router1 = Router();

router1.get("/", async (req, res) => {

      // I want to get here :id from router2 in file2

})
```

And *file2.js* (in the same directory for simplicity):

```
import Router from "express-promise-router";

import { router1 } from "./file1";

export const router2 = Router();

router2.use("/:id/path", router1);
```

I want to use `/:id` from *file2.js* in *file1.js* (see my comment in example code).

How can I do that?
In other words, how can I percolate `'/:something'` parameter down the routers chain?

Note - this doesn't work:

```
router1.get("/", async (req, res) => {

      const { params: {id} } = req;

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer.
From [express api](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html):
[image]

So should add the option `mergeParams` set to `true` when declaring the router handler.

In general:
`const router = express.Router({mergeParams: true});`.

For the question's example code in *file1.js*:

```
import Router from "express-promise-router";

export const router1 = Router({mergeParams: true});

router1.get("/", async (req, res) => {

      const { params: {id} } = req; // now this works

})
```